# Julia datatypes: When should you use a struct, Dict, named tuple or Dataframe?

Tags: types, julia

When should I use a struct, mutable struct, Dict, named tuple or DataFrame in Julia? Mutability and performance must be factors in deciding which data type to use. But when should I use each type?

Comment: This is a tough one for StackOverflow - I feel it would be better suited to the Julia Discourse for a more open-ended discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will try posting there also.

Comment: Note that the two concepts (mutability and performance) are often antagonist, altought you should at the end benchmark for your specific case. Consider also if you need to dispach based on your data.. With struct it is easy, with tuples somehow possible but messy, with Dict or DataFrames it isn't..

Comment: I think it can not be answered generally, because it really depends on type of data, amount of data and type of operations you are doing with such data.